# How to Update All Environment Variables in a Cmd Instance when Running a C# Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, terminal, environment-variables

I am developing a .NET 7 CLI that use user inputs, files, directories, and environment variables. I want to make sure that the cmd instance's environment variables remain up-to-date even after the program has exited.

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

```
C:\>set :: Show all environment variables
MyEnvironmentVariable=value1

C:\>MyProgram.exe
* Doing this and that *
* Refreshing environment variables *

C:\>set
MyEnvironmentVariable=value2
```

---

I've attempted a few solutions, but they didn't work. These include:

- Requesting ChatGPT to create a separate class that refreshes the environment variables
- Copying [RefreshEnv.cmd](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/develop/src/chocolatey.resources/redirects/RefreshEnv.cmd) from chocolatey and doing

  - `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\path\\to\\RefreshEnv.cmd")`
  - `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\path\\to\\RefreshEnv.cmd").WaitForExit()`
  - `new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "C:\\path\\to\\RefreshEnv.cmd");`

Comment: Any changes you make to environment variables *within* a process can't affect the environment variables of the *parent* process. Environment variables just don't work like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [take combo box choice and use choice as SETX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75225452/take-combo-box-choice-and-use-choice-as-setx)