# Why is the Powershell ExecutionPolicy different between my .NetCore application and Powershell 7?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

I have a .NetCore application running in Windows 10 that is attempting to run some scripts with PowerShell.

**I'm using the following Automation Library**

```
System.Management.Automation, Version=7.3.3.0
```

I have the ExecutionPolicy set for LocalMachine set to Unrestricted by running the following command in the Powershell 7 app:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -scope LocalMachine
```

**I check the ExecutionPolicy settings via:**

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
```

**I see the following output:**

```
      Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine       Unrestricted
```

**In my .NetCore application I run the following code snippet:**

```
var psInstance = PowerShell.Create();
psInstance.AddScript("Get-ExecutionPolicy -List");
var output = psInstance.Invoke();
```

**If I examine the output, I see the following:**

```
[0] {@{Scope=MachinePolicy; ExecutionPolicy=Undefined}} System.Management.Automation.PSObject
[1] {@{Scope=UserPolicy; ExecutionPolicy=Undefined}}    System.Management.Automation.PSObject
[2] {@{Scope=Process; ExecutionPolicy=Undefined}}   System.Management.Automation.PSObject
[3] {@{Scope=CurrentUser; ExecutionPolicy=Undefined}}   System.Management.Automation.PSObject
[4] {@{Scope=LocalMachine; ExecutionPolicy=Undefined}}  System.Management.Automation.PSObject
```

It seems like the execution policies within my application are not in synch with those I set directly through Powershell.

Why don't the two sets of ExecutionPolicies match up?

**Further more, if I attempt to run the following:**

```
var psInstance = PowerShell.Create();
psInstance.AddScript("Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name ""Language.TextToSpeech~~~fr-FR~0.0.1.0"" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty State";);
var output = psInstance.Invoke();
```

**I get the following error:**

> The 'Get-WindowsCapability' command was found in the module 'Dism',
> but the module could not be loaded due to the following error:  [File
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Dism\Dism.psm1
> cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
> For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.] For more information, run 'Import-Module Dism'.

**If I run:**

```
var script = "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force; Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name ""Language.TextToSpeech~~~fr-FR~0.0.1.0"" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty State";
psInstance.AddScript(script);
var output = psInstance.Invoke();
```

The command works as expected.

We don't want to have to set the ExecutionPolicy each time we run a script.
We want to leverage the execution polices on the local machine.
Why I can't I get this to work as expected?
Is there another way I should be setting ExecutionPolicy at the machine level?

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73999216/10024425

Comment: @user09938 - We are using .Net 7. Could part of the problem we're seeing is because we are .NetCore instead of standard .Net framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) has analogous, but separate [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies)  setting from *Windows PowerShell*:

- *Windows PowerShell* uses the *registry* to store the execution policy settings (for both the `Machine` and `CurrentUser` scopes).

  - Since both `powershell.exe` and Windows PowerShell SDK-based  projects consult these registry locations, the same effective policy applies to both environments.
- By contrast, *PowerShell (Core) 7+* uses `powershell.config.json` *files*.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - In the case of the *machine*-scope policy, that file is looked for *in the directory of the host executable*.

    - Therefore, when you use the *PowerShell SDK* in your own .NET application, *your* executable is the host executable - unlike in *interactive* sessions / CLI calls, where it is `pwsh.exe`.
  - It follows that .NET (Core) applications, which of necessity use the PowerShell (Core) SDK, do *not* see the machine-scope execution setting in effect for interactive sessions / [`pwsh` CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) calls - though a *user*-scope setting - if defined - *does* apply.

---

**Solution options**:

- Most robust: **Set the execution policy in the *process* scope**, every time your application runs, **as part of your PowerShell SDK session initialization**.

  - This overrides any persistently configured user- or machine-code settings (except if your execution policies are GPO-controlled, in which case modifying the GPOs is the *only* way to change the execution policy).
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68942672/45375) for sample code.
- **Set the execution policy persistently in the *user* scope**:

  - `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser`

    - Note: `RemoteSigned` is a more secure choice.
    - This works, because the user-scope `powershell.config.json` file location is only related to the user's home directory, and therefore the same for interactive /CLI and SDK sessions.
  - Obviously, you'd have to do that for every user that should be able to run your application.
- **Bundle a `powershell.config.json` file with your application** (place it alongside your executable); sample content:

  ```
  {
    "Microsoft.PowerShell:ExecutionPolicy": "RemoteSigned"
  }
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Given PowerShell (Core)'s *cross-platform* nature, using the Windows-only *registry* is no longer an option.</sup>