# How to prevent powershell from opening two windows during script execution?

Tags: vb.net, powershell, visual-studio, console-application

I have a simple powershell script which automates emailing an XML file when executed.

I have a VB.NET console application written in Visual Basic that calls the powershell script within the program to execute once certain parameters are met.

The calling of the powershell script works, and powershell executes as anticipated but for whatever reason the powershell script executes twice.  This normally wouldn't be an issue but it sends duplicate emails because of this when it should only be sending one.

Below is the code for calling the powershell script:

```
 Public Sub SendDaEmailMakeXMLFile()
     Using p As Process = New Process
         p.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo() With {
             .CreateNoWindow = True,
             .UseShellExecute = True,
             .FileName = "C:\SVMXEmailAutomation.ps1"
         }
         p.Start()
         p.WaitForExit()
         p.Close()




     End Using
 End Sub
```

The second window pops up and executes instantly If I remove the WaitforExit() command shown below:
[image]

If I leave the WaitforExit() command in place the first window will work as anticipated, close, and then the second instance will pop up directly after and execute.

Have I a made a mistake in syntax?  I have no error output on my logs.

Thank you for your review.

Comment: On the surface of it, it seems more likely your function is being called twice - if you replace the command with "notepad.exe" for example, do you get two notepad applications opening, or does this only happen when you call a ps1 script? If you add some logging like "entering SendDaEmailMakeXMLFile" in your VB.Net code, do you see that twice in your logs or only once?

Comment: If you set `.UseShellExecute = False,`, set `.FileName` to the powershell executable and `.Arguments` to `$"-File ""{[path to your script]}"""`, does it do the same? If so, double execution somewhere as already mentioned.

Comment: @mclayton you are absolutely correct.  I followed the steps you listed and when replacing the command with "notepad.exe" it does indeed open two notepad windows as for logging I do see that twice when logging is added.  What would possibly call the function twice though as its not specified why in the logs?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing the rest of your code. Try adding a breakpoint inside SendDaEmailMakeXMLFile and review the functions up the call stack, or add more logging in the calling functions to see if *they're* being called twice as well - basically work backwards until you find the culprit...

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74005878/10024425

Comment: @mclayton Thank you for the great advice sir.  I will follow the steps provided!

Comment: @Jimi for whatever reason just on the .Arguments variable I am getting a syntax error.  As soon as I work through that I will let you know if double execution is happening or not.

Comment: If you have an old version of VB.NET that doesn't support interpolated strings (`$"{variable}"`), then just, e.g., concatenate the parts. So change `dim psPath = "C:\SVMXEmailAutomation.ps1"  $"-File ""{psPath]}"""` in `"-File " & ChrW(34) & "C:\SVMXEmailAutomation.ps1" & ChrW(34)`

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for the advice.  It still does the same so I take it I have to track down the double execution culprit.  Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you for your help and assistance!

After going through log files and using breakpoints, I determined that where I had the code placed within its own sub class, it was causing the code to execute twice.  I simply removed the SendDaEmailMakeXMLFile() Public Sub Class and placed the previously listed code in the question above in the Main Sub body of the full program.

Doing this only causes the code to execute one time as it is supposed to do.
Hopefully this helps someone else in the future if they encounter this problem!